# ActionScript 3 Error when dynamically playing audio

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, air

I am writing a game for Air iOS. I have an audio file, saved in the same directory as my .fla file. Here is the code I am using to play it:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;

var snd:Sound = new Sound(new  URLRequest("507560_-BlastProcess-.mp3")); 
snd.play(0, 40);
```

This is the error I get when testing in thew Air Debug Launcher:

```
[SWF] Spike%20Jungle.swf - 72668 bytes after decompression
Error #2044: Unhandled IOErrorEvent:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error.
    at SpikeJungle_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[SpikeJungle_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:128]
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/loadInitialContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playRawContent()
    at runtime::ContentPlayer/playContent()
    at runtime::AppRunner/run()
    at ADLAppEntry/run()
    at global/runtime::ADLEntry()
[UnloadSWF] Spike%20Jungle.swf
Test Movie terminated.
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: what is at line 128 of your `MainTimeLine` class?

Comment: StreamError - that is either a file not found, a security restriction or you are trying to play a file which is not fully loaded - can't say for sure, maybe it is ok to start playing immediately, but I would first wait for the loader to fire a Event.COMPLETE and only then play.

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko I tried this:
`import flash.events.Event; 
import flash.media.Sound; 
import flash.net.URLRequest; 
 
var s:Sound = new Sound(); 
s.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSoundLoaded); 
var req:URLRequest = new URLRequest("HexagonForce.mp3"); 
s.load(req); 
 
function onSoundLoaded(event:Event):void 
{ 
    var localSound:Sound = event.target as Sound; 
    localSound.play(); 
}`
but I still get the same error.

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas. Maybe the sound file itself is corrupted and cannot be read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either need a cross-domain or the path to the file is incorrect.

Your AIR app is probably not running in the same folder as your mp3. See where your compiled air app is being stored and move the mp3 to that folder.

http://www.judahfrangipane.com/blog/2007/02/15/error-2032-stream-error/

You may also want to use a SoundChannel so you can stop the sound